# Using canvas to display a picture pixel by pixel within secs

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

For learning purpose, I am trying to display an image pixel by pixel in a canvas within a few seconds, below is the code I write

```
var timeStamps = [];
var intervals = [];
var c = document.getElementById('wsk');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    img = new Image(),
    i;
img.onload = init;
img.src = "http://placehold.it/100x100/000000";
var points = [];
function init(){
  ctx.canvas.width = img.width;
  ctx.canvas.height = img.height;
  for (i=0; i<img.width*img.height; i++) {
    points.push(i);
  }
  window.m = points.length;
  var sec = 10; //animation duration

  function animate(t) {
    timeStamps.push(t);
    var pointsPerFrame = Math.floor(img.width*img.height/sec/60)+1;
    var start = Date.now();
    for (j=0; j<pointsPerFrame; j++) {
      var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*m--); //Pick a point
      temp = points[i];
      points[i] = points[m];
      points[m] = temp;   //swap the point with the last element of the points array
      var point = new Point(i%img.width,Math.floor(i/img.width));  //get(x,y)
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,1)";
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
      ctx.fillRect(point.x,point.y,1,1); //DRAW DOZENS OF POINTS WITHIN ONE FRAME
    }
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";//Only display the overlapping part of the new content and old cont
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); //image could be with transparent areas itself, so only draw the image on those points that are already on screen, exluding points that don't overlap with the image.
    var time = Date.now()-start;
    intervals.push(time);
    if( m > 0 ) requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  animate();
}

function Point(x,y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
```

Live test: www.weiwei-tv.com/test.php. 
I was expecting the dots would appear total randomly and eventually fill out the whole 100*100 canvas. What real happens is every time only the upper half of the picture gets displayed but many dots in the lower half are missed. I guess the problem is with the technique I use to randomly pick up dots, I get it from this [page](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/), but I can't find anything wrong in it.

Another thing I notice is that the `intervals` are mostly 1ms or 0ms, which means javascript takes very little time draw the `100*100/10/60` dots and draw image upon it within every frame. However, the differences between `timeStamps` are mostly 30~50ms, which should be about 16ms(1000/60). I am not sure if this also plays a part in the failure of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the index of the points array to compute the point coordinates. You need to use the value of the chosen point (which is moved to the m-th position).

So, change

```
var point = new Point(i%img.width,Math.floor(i/img.width));
```

To

```
var point = new Point(points[m]%img.width,Math.floor(points[m]/img.width));
```